# Proxy server on Debian

Tags: debian, proxy

I'd like to create a simple HTTP(S) proxy allowing only certain IPs XXX.XXX.XXX.* and requiring authentication. Also it won't be forwarding IP of the guest. What solution should I choose? If you have created such a thing using some tutorial, link would be welcome.

Comment: Allowing certain IPs to use it as a proxy, or allowing only certain IPs to be accessed through it?  I suspect you mean the former, but I hate to guess.

Comment: Yes, I mean allowing certain IPs to use it as a proxy

Comment: Do a web search for "how to set up a proxy server". Follow any of the 17 million links.

Comment: Such an answer is quite useless, much more valuable would be something like "Take a look at Nginx" or even adding "because it's lightweight"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Squid (http://www.squid-cache.org/) is the most popular Linux proxy. It is very easy to configure for simple use case as yours. Also, it is available in binary form for debian so simple `apt-get install squid` should do.

Here you have configuration examples: http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples
which you can pick and choose to work best for you.

As there is authentication involved, you have to consider logging/accountability and probably generate some reports later on.

Comment: Thanks, it seems Squid is a good solution because of its wide spread.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using NGINX on my own side and deeply worked with SQUID, but SQUID is really usefull for corporation and/or administrators which aim to save bandwith and other advanced proxy features like transparent traffic interception etc.